# How can I bind multiple canvas elements together in order to change their color simultaneously?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So, these are the lines which I have created/drawn:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

f= Frame(root)
f.pack()
c = Canvas(f,bg = "black")
c.pack()
line1 = c.create_line(10,0,10,50,fill = "white",activefill = "blue",tag = "one")
line_side1 = c.create_line(0,25,10,25,fill= "white", activefill = "blue",tag = "one")
line2 = c.create_line(30,0,30,50,fill = "white",activefill = "blue",tag = "one")
line_side2 = c.create_line(30,25,40,25,fill= "white", activefill = "blue",tag = "one")
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So, now I want that all the lines should get the color blue when I hover the mouse over them.

I've tried using the `tag_bind` option, but it would be helpful if you could show me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the answer by @AleksanderMonk works fine, I think binding to the tag `"one"` would be easier in this case, especially when you're planning on making more lines. You can use the tag instead of the id in both the `tag_bind` and the `itemconfigure` function:

```
from tkinter import *

def change_color(event):
    if event.type == "7":   # Enter
        event.widget.itemconfigure("one", fill="blue")
    elif event.type == "8": # Leave
        event.widget.itemconfigure("one", fill="white")

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
c = Canvas(f, bg="black")
f.pack()    
c.pack()

line1      = c.create_line(10, 0,10,50, fill="white", tag="one")
line_side1 = c.create_line( 0,25,10,25, fill="white", tag="one")
line2      = c.create_line(30, 0,30,50, fill="white", tag="one")
line_side2 = c.create_line(30,25,40,25, fill="white", tag="one")

c.tag_bind("one", "<Enter>", change_color)
c.tag_bind("one", "<Leave>", change_color)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need to do is make a list of all line ids (line1, line2,..) and on hover just change color for all items in the list.

```
from tkinter import *

def set_color(event):
    for x in all_ids:
        c.itemconfig(x, fill="blue")
    return

def return_color(event):
    for x in all_ids:
        c.itemconfig(x, fill="white")
    return

all_ids = []

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
f.pack()
c = Canvas(f, bg="black")
c.pack()

all_ids.append(c.create_line(10, 0, 10, 50, fill="white"))
all_ids.append(c.create_line(0, 25, 10, 25, fill="white"))
all_ids.append(c.create_line(30, 0, 30, 50, fill="white"))
all_ids.append(c.create_line(30, 25, 40, 25, fill="white"))


for x in all_ids:
    c.tag_bind(x, '<Enter>', set_color)
    c.tag_bind(x, '<Leave>', return_color)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For brevity, you could also do the binding of the lines in a loop similar to the one in your color functions (e.g. `for x in all_ids: c.tag_bind(x, '<Enter>', SetColor)`)